# Is the weak$^*$ topology the same as the inherited product topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

> (Folland's page 169) Let $X$ be a normed vector space. Let $B^*:= \{ f \in X^* \,: \, ||f|| \le 1 \}$  be the unit ball in $V^*$ under the operator norm.  $B^*$ is compact in $X^*$ in the weak$^*$ topology.

In his proof, he stated that

> We may identify $B^*$ with $D:= \prod D_x$, where $D_x:= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \, : \, |z| \le ||x|| \}$. Then the weak$^*$ topology inherited in $B^*$  coincides with the product topology.

So I tried to proved this; and I proved the following:

> **Claim:** If $V^*$ is identified as a subset of $\prod D_x$, then the weak $^*$ topology is the same as the product topology inherited.
>
> **Proof:**
>
> 1. Let $\tau_1, \tau_2$ denote the weak $^*$ topology, product topology respectively.
> 2. A basis element of $V^*$ is of the form $U:=\bigcap_{i=1}^n B(x_i, f, \varepsilon) \cap V^*$ for some $f \in V^*$ where 
>      $$ B(x_i,f, \varepsilon) = \{ g \in V^* \, : \, |g(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\varepsilon \} $$ 
>      Hence $h \in U$ iff 
>      $$ |h(x_i)-f(x_i)| < \varepsilon \text{ for all } i \Leftrightarrow h \in V_* \cap h \in \prod_i B(f(x_i), \varepsilon)  $$ 
>      So $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$.
> 3. Conversely, let $U:=\prod B(\alpha_i, \varepsilon)$ (only finitely many $i$ are not whole space.)  be any basis element of $\prod \mathbb{C}_x$. We can define a linear functional, $g \in V^*$, such that $g(x_i) = \alpha_i$ for finitely many elements $i$. **This can be extended to $V$ by Hahn Banach**. Hence, $U \cap V^*$ corresponds to the basis element $V^*$
>      $$ \bigcap_{i=1}^n B(x_i,g, \varepsilon) $$
>      Thus, $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$.

I have not found any reference for the proof of these two topologies. So (i) is my proof correct? (ii) is Hahn Banach necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 3) you are proving that the restriction of product topology to $X^{*}$ is the weak* topology.  So you have to take a basic open set in $\prod D_x$ and intersect it with $X^{*}$. This makes 3) evident and you do not have to construct any $x^{*}$ using Hahn - Banach Theorem.

Comment: Yes, I take a basic open set and intersect it with $X^*$ - but I have to show this set is a basic open set in the weak $^*$ topology, sorry, but why is this evident?

Comment: A set of the type  $\{x^{*} \in X^{*}: |x^{*} (x_i)-a_i| \leq \epsilon_i$ for  $1\leq i \leq n\}$ is not necessarily a basic open set in $X^{*}$ but it is open set in the weak* topology. This is enough to prove the result.

Comment: I am confused. A set of your written type is already open (assuming we have $<$ instead of $\le$) in product topology. Are you sure you are not referring 2)? For 3) we need to show: 

An arbitrary open set $$\{ |f(x_i) - a_i| < \varepsilon_i \text{ for } 1 \le i \le n \}$$ in $\prod \mathbb{C}_x$ when intersected with $B^*$ is an open set in $B^*$.

Comment: First a correction: I meant $<\epsilon_i$, not $\leq  \epsilon_i$. This set is open in weak* topology. Any set of the type $\{x^{*}: x^{*}(x_i) \in U_i,1\leq i \leq n\}$ where $U_i$'s are open sets is open in weak* topology

Comment: Ah, my bad, I think I was just confused. Thanks a lot.